# Trying to connect to server for ruby development

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and having trouble setting up my server.

I did all the gems installing and stuff have a `mysql2` server running but I can't connect to it trough my local host keep getting a error.

So I've tried changing the default server `gem` that is puma don't even know what that is to `webrick` which was recommended and my active record database to mysql2 I get this a error
I'll upload my server client connections and gemfile and such  if it is helpful.

But what I'm basically trying to do is setting up a server to test my ruby apps.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the mysql2 gem? Your screen shows that you only have sqlite3, which is obviously used to connect to sqlite databases

Answer (score 1):

You should check your database.yml and enters your connection parameters to your database.

Should appears something like this:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: tst_database
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "my_password_on_sql_installation"
  #socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

After that run your server searching your route and typing `rails server` on promt.